# How to auth with google-auth-library and firebase-admin?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin, google-auth-library

I am trying to use `firebase-admin` and found some inconsistency. 
I am trying to write some auth code with `google-auth-library` and `firebase-admin` and then got stuck on where to get client_id, client_secret. I feel it is something I can get from `admin` after `initializeApp` but failed to figure out how.

```
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const client = new OAuth2Client(
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,      ------> somewhere in `admin`?
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL
  );
```

THanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are rolling your own auth implementation, you may want to store your id + secret in [environment variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env).

If you are using the one Firebase provides as part of your app setup, I think you may be reinventing the wheel a bit, I would suggest reading through [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) to use their code examples as much as possible, as much of this is handled for you by the Firebase SDK automatically.

Comment: My case is different. I am using server side auth. I need authenticate my firebase function to retrieve gmail information. To do that, I need a Oauth client which requires me to have client key and client secret. See here: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/gcf-gmail-codelab/blob/master/pubsub/index.js#L131-L157

Comment: So the issue is I cannot get the access token from firebase-admin on server side so I have to reinvent the wheel: storing and retrieving tokens.